# Amazon SES Email Listening Architecture - Review

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

Theme: Receive emails and save it in s3  and then process it.( igonre the outlook in diagram, users can send email directly to Amazon ses)

Architecture Design approach - Amazon for Email Listening from java Application. Can anyone who had implemented this kind of approach review this and list down the challenges?
use this approach if you are trying it - we tested this approach and its working fine.

More details on Amazon ses: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html

I will upload a detailed steps soon.

[image]

Note: This prototype is in Production now. It can be taken as example prototype.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve with this approach. Sharing the theme would help in giving more accurate insights